# AWK: How to get count of column couples?

Tags: awk

I have a CSV file made of many **couples** of columns, each couple has `code_###` and `name_###`.

```
code_boat|name_boat|year|code_color|name_color|code_size|name_size
1|jeanneau|2000|#00f|blue|5|small
2|bavaria|2005|#00f|blue|10|big
1|jeanneau|2010|#f00|red|10|big
2|bavaria|2008|#000|white|5|small
3|fountaine-pajot|2005|#f00|red|5|small
1|jeanneau|2012|#000|white|5|small
```

```
code_boat │       name_boat │ year │ code_color │ name_color │ code_size │ name_size
──────────┼─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼────────────┼───────────┼───────────
        1 │        jeanneau │ 2000 │       #00f │       blue │         5 │     small
        2 │         bavaria │ 2005 │       #00f │       blue │        10 │       big
        1 │        jeanneau │ 2010 │       #f00 │        red │        10 │       big
        2 │         bavaria │ 2008 │       #000 │      white │         5 │     small
        3 │ fountaine-pajot │ 2005 │       #f00 │        red │         5 │     small
        1 │        jeanneau │ 2012 │       #000 │      white │         5 │     small
```

I need to **count** how many times these **couples** are used, and keep the couple index:

```
couple_index │  code │            name │ count
─────────────┼───────┼─────────────────┼───────
           0 │     1 │        jeanneau │     3
           0 │     2 │         bavaria │     2
           0 │     3 │ fountaine-pajot │     1
           2 │  #000 │           white │     2
           2 │  #f00 │             red │     2
           2 │  #00f │            blue │     2
           4 │     5 │           small │     4
           4 │    10 │             big │     2
```

```
0|1|jeanneau|3
0|2|bavaria|2
0|3|fountaine-pajot|1
2|#000|white|2
2|#f00|red|2
2|#00f|blue|2
4|5|small|4
4|10|big|2
```

I know how to do it couple by couple with `awk`, but I'd like to do all at once, because the csv files are pretty big.

```
awk -F'|' '{c[$39" "$40]++} END{for (i in c) {if (c[i]>0) print i,c[i]}}' myfile.csv
```

Comment: what is your `awk` version (`awk --version`)?

Comment: please update the question with the actual data from your file (`cat myfile.csv`) and the actual data you're looking to generate; you've mentioned in a comment that you've reformatted the data for inclusion in the question (eg, what's currently in the question is not a 'normal' pipe character); to improve the chances of receiving a working solution we need to see the actual data

Comment: @markp-fuso GNU Awk `5.1.1` on  macos

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for your comment, I cleaned my question. Two answers below actually fixed my issue and helped me a lot in better understanding `awk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions/Understandings:

- from OP's comments the actual data file is pipe-delimited with no leading/trailing spaces in fields (see modified input file - below)
- output is to be generated in the same format (ie, pipe-delimited with no leading/trailing spaces in fields)

Sample input file:

```
$ cat myfile.csv
boat_CODE|boat_NAME|color_CODE|color_NAME|size_CODE|size_NAME
1|jeanneau|#00f|blue|5|small
2|bavaria|#00f|blue|10|big
1|jeanneau|#f00|red|10|big
2|bavaria|#000|white|5|small
3|fountaine-pajot|#f00|red|5|small
1|jeanneau|#000|white|5|small
```

**NOTE:** will need to come back and modify the code depending on what, if any, header record(s) actually exists in the file

---

One `GNU awk` idea making use of arrays of arrays (aka multi-dimensional arrays):

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
NR>1  { for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2)
            counts[(i-1)][$i][$(i+1)]++
      }
END   { print "couple_index","CODE","NAME","count"
        for (ndx=0;ndx<NF;ndx+=2)
            for (code in counts[ndx])
                for (name in counts[ndx][code])
                    print ndx,code,name,counts[ndx][code][name]
      }
' myfile.csv
```

This generates:

```
couple_index|CODE|NAME|count
0|1|jeanneau|3
0|2|bavaria|2
0|3|fountaine-pajot|1
2|#000|white|2
2|#00f|blue|2
2|#f00|red|2
4|5|small|4
4|10|big|2
```

OP has mentioned in comments they are running on macOS; assuming `GNU awk` is not available we can use a multi-value hash as the index for a single-dimensional array, eg:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
NR>1  { for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2)
            counts[(i-1) FS $i FS $(i+1)]++
      }
END   { print "couple_index","CODE","NAME","count"
        for (i in counts)
            print i,counts[i]
      }
' myfile.csv
```

This generates:

```
couple_index|CODE|NAME|count
0|3|fountaine-pajot|1
2|#f00|red|2
4|5|small|4
0|1|jeanneau|3
4|10|big|2
2|#000|white|2
0|2|bavaria|2
2|#00f|blue|2
```

---

**Sorting:**

If the result needs to be sorted this will probably be easier in `bash` via the `sort` command:

- remove the `print "couple_index","CODE","NAME","count"` from both `awk` solutions; instead move this up to the command line
- pipe the `awk` results to `sort`

One idea:

```
echo "couple_index|CODE|NAME|count"                      > result.csv
awk '.....' myfile.csv | sort -t'|' -k1,1n -k2,2V -k3,3 >> result.csv
```

Both `awk` solutions generate:

```
$ cat result.csv
couple_index|CODE|NAME|count
0|1|jeanneau|3
0|2|bavaria|2
0|3|fountaine-pajot|1
2|#000|white|2
2|#00f|blue|2
2|#f00|red|2
4|5|small|4
4|10|big|2
```

Comment: What do mean `1n`, `2V` and `3` after `-k` option when sorting ?

Comment: `-t'|'` => field delimiter; `-k1,1n` => sort by fields 1 to 1 using n'umeric; sort; `-k2,2V` => sort by fields 2 to 2 using `V`ersion sort; `-k3,3` => sort by fields 3 to 3 using default string sort; `-k#,#` is a `KEYDEF` while `n` and `V` are additional options; `-k1n` says to sort fields 1 to end-of-line using 'n'umeric sort, while `-k1,1n` limits the 1st sort criteria to just field #1; see `man sort` and/or web searches for `sort` examples

Answer (score 2):

If the couples are always one next to another, you can easily do it with a loop:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
     (FNR>2){for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) { k=$i OFS $(i+1); c[k]++; d[k] = i } }
     END{for (k in c) print d[k],k,c[k] }' file
```

This does not take care of issues that could be the result misalignment or typos.

If the table has intermediate columns that are of no interest to the problem at hand, it is paramount to process the header first:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
     (FNR==1) { for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) if ($i ~ /_CODE *$/) { idx[i] } }
     (FNR>2)  { for(i in idx) { k=$i OFS $(i+1); c[k]++; d[k] = i } }
     END{for (k in c) print d[k],k,c[k] }' file
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The two columns (code and name) of couples are always next to each other, but the CSV files also have other columns in between couples, that why I need to give the couples index explicitely.

Comment: This is missing information in your question.

Comment: Thanks. I don't get any result, maybe because I'm using awk on macos. Also, I'm replace `($i ~ /_CODE *$/)` by `($i ~ /^Code *$/)` because couples columns names are actually like `Code Country` and `Libelle Country` (with sapces in it).

Comment: @DevonDahon from looking at the input, I believe the vertical-line-character is not a regular [vertical line/pipe](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+007C) (`|`) but the [box-drawing-light-vertical character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2502)  The code I present has a regular pipe, so just update the line `FS=OFS="|"` into `FS=OFS="│"`

Comment: This pipe was just to make a nicer table, a regular pipe is used in the CSV in which there is no extra space like in my table.

Comment: @DevonDahon When running this in https://ideone.com/qVPoBy, it works

Answer (score 1):

I would implement counting of pairs as follows, let `file.txt` content be

```
boat_CODE |         boat_NAME | color_CODE | color_NAME | size_CODE | size_NAME
        1 |          jeanneau |       #00f |       blue |         5 |     small
        2 |           bavaria |       #00f |       blue |        10 |       big
        1 |          jeanneau |       #f00 |        red |        10 |       big
        2 |           bavaria |       #000 |      white |         5 |     small
        3 |   fountaine-pajot |       #f00 |        red |         5 |     small
        1 |          jeanneau |       #000 |      white |         5 |     small
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[^[:space:]|]+"}NR>1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2){c[$i" "$(i+1)]+=1}}END{for(i in c){printf "%-25s%s\n",i,c[i]}}' file.txt
```

output

```
10 big                   2
#00f blue                2
#f00 red                 2
2 bavaria                2
5 small                  4
3 fountaine-pajot        1
#000 white               2
1 jeanneau               3
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field consist of one or more (`+`) characters which are not (`^`) whitespace (`[:space:]`) and `|`. Then for each row after first (`NR>1`) I iterate using `for` loop with step being 2, and increase value in array `c` under key being concatenation of this column value and space and next column value. After all lines are processing I `printf` key-value pairs from array `c`, with key being leftjusted in string of length 25 (feel free to change this to fit your needs). **Disclaimer**: This solution assume there is never whitespace inside value.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, that's almost what I need. But actually, I need to tell it the column index of each couple I need, also, I need to use this column index to know which kind of couple the count concerns. My CS files are actually made like this: `foo|bar|123`, I mean separated by `|` with no whitespaces to trim.